# I've set an editor as default, how do I call it to open files in a shell?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

**EDIT** I thought of a better way to phrase the question.

How can I find the alias that Ubuntu is using for a different text editor? Rather than using nano by typing `nano file.txt`, i'd like to be able to type `sublime file.txt` to open sublime editor. I don't know where to look to find these aliases.

`sudo update-alternatives --config editor` does not show it as a choice, I only see the 'default' editors, like Nano and vim.tiny.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is identifiable as a text file then passing it to `xdg-open` will open it in your text editor. If it identifies as some other type though, it will open the file in the appropriate application instead.

**EDIT:**

`xdg-mime query default <mimetype>` will give you the .desktop file for the application associated with a MIME type. From there you need to parse the file to get the executable name from it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
export EDITOR=vim or nano or any editor name
```

or copy this line and write in .bashrc or .profile file